# Does this sentence sound natural?

Tags: phrase-usage

If I'm at a bar and I want, for example, drink my cup of coffee at a table outside, is

> can I take it outside?

a good way to say that? 
Also, does

> can I take it out?

have the same meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two sentences may have two different meanings

> Can I take it outside?

is the literal meaning of carrying *something* outside, it implies you already have your cup of coffee in hand.

> Can I have it outside?

would be said if you are asking about where you can be served.

> Can I take it out?

might be understood to ask if you can take it with you as a "take-out" (AmE), "to-go" (AmE) or "take-away" (BrE), which may mean you are asking for a paper cup for your coffee to take *somewhere*.  A better formulation might be

> Can I have this to go?

"Out" is used in general to mean a distance away

> Let's go out tonight.

"outside" means out in the open air but possibly in a nearby area

> Let's go outside on the terrace.